# Perl: multithreaded server with Coro and AnyEvent

Tags: multithreading, perl, anyevent

I am a newbie in Perl, so in educational purposes I am developing multithreaded server using AnyEvent and Coro. The client sends to server list of directory paths and server responses with listing of these directories.

I am using tcp_server and AnyEvent::Handle for connections handling, and for each client I want server to check thread pool (which is actually pool of coros) for free coro to handle request. When handling request is finished, I want coro to wait for another client instead of finishing.

However, it seems like at the end of handle_request sub, coro is destroyed and not avaliable anymore.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use v5.18;

use AnyEvent;                           
use AnyEvent::Socket qw(tcp_server);    
use AnyEvent::Handle;                  

use Coro;

use Class::Struct;

print("Server is running...\n");

# dirs function

sub print_dirs {

    my $dir_list = $_[0];
    my @dirs = split(" ", $dir_list);
    my $result = "";

    for my $dir (@dirs) {
        if (opendir my $dirent, $dir) {
            my @files = readdir $dirent;
            closedir $dirent;
            $result = $result . "\nContents of $dir:\r\n" . join("\r\n", @files) . "\r\n";
        } else {
            $result = $result . "Failed to open $dir: $!\r\n";
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

# thread struct
struct clt_thread => {
    id => '$',
    thread => '$',
    is_busy => '$',
    args => '$',
    client => '$',
    clt_key => '$'
};

my $threads_num = 16;
my $thread_id = 0;
my @pool = ();

# handling request

my $cv = AE::cv;
my %client = ();

sub handle_request {

        my $thread_id = shift;
        my $thread;
        foreach my $thr (@pool) {
            if ($thr->id == $thread_id) { $thread = $thr; }
        }
        my $self = $thread->client;
        my $client_key = $thread->clt_key;
        my $dir_list = $thread->args;
        if ($thread->client != '') {

            say "Directories read: " . $dir_list . "\n";
            my @clients = keys %client;

            for my $key (grep {$_ ne $client_key} @clients) {
                my $response = print_dirs($dir_list);
                $client{$key}->push_write("$response");
                $self->push_shutdown;
                delete $client{$client_key};
                delete $client{$self};
            }

        }
        $thread->is_busy(0);
        Coro::cede();
}

# threads creation

for my $i (0..$threads_num) {
    my $coro = new Coro(\&handle_request, $thread_id);
    my $thread = clt_thread->new(id => $thread_id, thread => $coro, is_busy => 0, args => '', client => '', clt_key => '');
    push @pool, $thread;
    $thread_id = $thread_id+1;
}

# tcp server creation - main part

tcp_server '127.0.0.1', 8015, sub {

    my ($fh, $host, $port) = @_;
    my $client_key = "$host:$port";

    my $hdl = AnyEvent::Handle->new(
            fh => $fh,
            poll => 'r',
            on_read => sub {
                    my ($self) = @_;

                    foreach my $thr (@pool) {
                        if (!($thr->is_busy)) {
                        $thr->client($self);
                        $thr->args($self->rbuf); 
                        $thr->clt_key($client_key);
                        $thr->is_busy(1);
                        $thr->thread->ready();
                        return;
                        }   
                    }
            },
            on_error => sub {
                say "Something went wrong: $!\n";
            },
    );

    $client{$client_key} = $hdl;
    $client{$hdl} = $hdl;
};

$cv->recv;
```

I have already tried using infinite loop inside handle_request, but this way everything stops working at all. Do you have any ideas how to fix that? I suppose using Coro::AnyEvent to integrate coroutines into event loop might be solution. Can it be helpful in my case?

Thans for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread exits when `handle_request` exits, so you want to wrap the body of `handle_request` in an infinite loop.

You also want to use `Coro::schedule;` instead of `Coro::cede;` to wait for `->ready` to be called again before continuing.

That first loop in `handle_request` can be reduced to `my $thread = $pool[$thread_id];`.

Untested fix:

```
sub handle_request {
   my ($thread_id) = @_;
   my $thread = $pool[$thread_id];

   while (1) {
      my $self       = $thread->client;
      my $client_key = $thread->clt_key;
      my $dir_list   = $thread->args;

      ...

      $thread->is_busy(0);
      Coro::schedule();
   }
}
```

---

That said, the following is the approach I'd use:

```
use Coro;
use Coro::Channel;

use constant NUM_WORKERS => 16;

sub worker {
   my ($job) = @_;

   my $self       = $job->client;
   my $client_key = $job->clt_key;
   my $dir_list   = $job->args;

   ...
}

{
   my $q = Coro::Channel->new();

   my @threads =
      map {
         async {
            while ( my $job = $q->get() ) {
               eval { worker($job); 1 }
                  or warn $@;
            }
         }
      }
         1..NUM_WORKERS;

   ...
   on_read => sub {
      my ($self) = @_;
      $q->put({
         client  => $self,
         clt_key => $client_key,
         args    => $self->rbuf,
      });
   }
   ...

   $cv->recv;
   $q->shutdown;
   $_->join for @threads;
}
```

This is the same approach I'd use with real threads (using Thread::Queue instead of Coro::Channel).